# How to check for an erroneous primary key parameter in a filtered django ORM query?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I'm given a list of primary keys of model instances on which I'm to perform an operation (eg `delete()`). I could do:

```
Widgets.objects.filter(pk__in=keys).delete()
```

However, then I wouldn't know if there were erroneous pks in `keys` that wouldn't have been caught by the filter.

What's the most efficient way to check that all the pks are legitimate before performing the operation? `len(keys) == Widgets.objects.filter(pk__in=keys).count()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the tuple returned from `delete` is the number of rows deleted. You can compare that with the length of the keys list.

Comment: Any way to do it *before* actually calling `delete()`? I'm trying to return 404 if one of the pks is wrong, without attempting to perform the operation.

Comment: The suggestion you make in the question would work fine.

Comment: An alternative would be to start a transaction and then rollback + 404 if the number of deleted rows doesn't match or commit if it does. This runs the query only once.

That is still "attempting to perform the operation" but might be ok regardless?